# How to get energy eigenstates using plane wave basis wavefunction .hdf5 output from Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, quantum-mechanics, basis-sets, wavefunctions

When compiled with the HDF5 flag on, Quantum ESPRESSO (QE) saves wavefunctions in the .save folder. At each k-point, we have an $m\times n$ matrix, where $m$ are the complex number entries of eigenvectors in the plane wave basis, and $n$ are the bands.

However, I now desire an $n\times n$ matrix of eigenvectors in the energy eigenstate basis. Is there a way I can do this? I cannot think of ways to achieve this.

I asked a similar question a while ago: [How to understand the wavefunction outputed by QE with HDF5 format?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4266/how-to-understand-the-wavefunction-outputed-by-qe-with-hdf5-format), but I cannot seem to go further from there.

What I naively tried: I summed each row of each column to get a complex number for each band, but this can at most give me probability amplitudes one way or another, to my understanding. Not eigenvectors.

Comment: Or, maybe my question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't make sense?

Comment: Also, why did you use the DFT tag here? There's better tags that could be used here!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.